# How can I define the types used in an array with a definition file when using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using the datatables plugin datatables.net as below:

```
 oTable = $('#dataTable').dataTable({ });
```

Here is some code that I have

```
$('#detailData')
    .on('click', '.sort-up', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var column = $(this).closest('th'),
            columnIndex = column.parent().children().index(column.get(0));
        oTable.fnSort([[columnIndex, 'asc']]);
        return false;
    })
```

This is giving me the following error with Typescript:

> "Incompatible types in array literal expression"

Can anyone give me some advice on how I could fix this? It does not seem to like the fact
that columnIndex is a number and 'asc' is a string. On Stack Overflow I saw the following:

```
var f: any[][] = [
    [Foo, [1, 2, 3]],
    [Bar, [7, 8, 9]],
];
```

I understand doing I need to do something like this but is there a way I can set up the 
definition of the fnSort function in a .d.ts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the job

```
oTable.fnSort([<any[]>[columnIndex, 'asc']]);
```

arrays should be of uniform type and since you have mixed types [number, string] it throws compilation error. casting it to any[] tells compiler that every value in an array is of type 'any' (which is true btw ;) ). compiler will then generate correct js.
its just a way to fool typescript compiler a bit

you can do it other way around also - convert columnIndex to string, but if you need it to be number then you have to cast array to any[]